# Unable to display User's Account information using global variable {!CurrentUser.accountId}. I pass this into my LWC to display info, but get an error

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, data-loader, global-variables

HTML:

```
<template>
  <!-- <lightning-record-form
  object-api-name={objectApiName}
  record-id={contactId}
  layout-type={layoutType}> 
  </lightning-record-form> -->

  <lightning-record-form record-id={userId} object-api-name="User" layout-type="Full" columns="1" mode="readonly">
  </lightning-record-form>


</template>
```

JS:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import CONTACT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Contact';
import USER_CONTACT_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/User.ContactId';
import USER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/User';
import FIRSTNAME_VALUE from '@salesforce/schema/User.FirstName';
import LASTNAME_VALUE from '@salesforce/schema/User.LastName';

export default class EditContactExternalForm extends LightningElement {
    // Expose recordId to get info from parent
    @api recordId;
    @api userIden;

    /*@wire(getRecord, { recordId : '$recordId', fields: [USER_CONTACT_FIELD]}) user;*/
    
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId : '$userId', fields: [FIRSTNAME_VALUE, LASTNAME_VALUE]}) userx;

    get contactId() {
        return getFieldValue(this.user.data, USER_CONTACT_FIELD);
    }

    get userId() {
      return this.userIden;
    }

    objectApiName1 = CONTACT_OBJECT;
    objectApiName2 = USER_OBJECT;
    layoutType = 'Full';

}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>57.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Page</target>
        <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightningCommunity__Default">
            <property name="recordId" type="String" required="false"/>
            <property name="userIden" type="String" required="false"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

[image: sharing settings]
[image: displayed error]
[image]